# How do I add timeout, in order to move to next client if current client has not sent any data?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

How do I add timeout, in order to move to next client if current client has not sent any data in Python? I have my all the connected clients stored in the `conn_clients` list.

Here's my code for receive function:

```
def receive(connection):
        curr_con = connection
        while True:
            message = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not message:
                print "Closing connection"
                conn_clients.remove(connection) #removing socket from list
                return
            send_all(curr_con, message)         #sending message to all cleints
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the operating system, and I'm not sure if this is applicable for Windows.

GLib provides timeout functions which you can start and tell to execute a function after a certain interval. I found [this article](http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/07/spawning-processes-using-glib.html) which shows how to connect g_io_add_watch to socket events (much cleaner that waiting for events) and simultaneously start a timer (from the same library). If the socket doesn't show activity in the time set, the function can abort the socket process.

Comment: I am developing on Windows.

Comment: Well, check it - Glib _is_ available for Windows, so this functionality might be too.

Comment: can this be implemented using socket.settimeout() ?

Comment: Yes - very possibly. I've never used that function, but it looks promising.